# Can an aircraft takeoff while another is still exiting the runway?

Tags: general-aviation

Today I was at a non towered airport and I just had landed, while I was beginning to turn off the runway, I saw a light sport behind me takeoff, while I was still on the runway. I was just starting my turn when I saw him fly over my back. Is this legal?

Comment: Hi Ben, welcome to aviation.stackexchange. Which country are you flying in?

Comment: Did the plane leave the ground before reaching your position when he started his roll?

Answer (score 7):

As noted by @randomhead in a comment below, in the U.S. at an airport with an operating control tower, a controller will not clear an aircraft for takeoff ([see FAA JO 7110.65Z, para. 3-9-6b.)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap3_section_9.html#3NJ3acJACK) until a preceding landing aircraft is  "clear of the runway" ([See this term in the Pilot/Controller Glossary](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg_html/glossary-c.html)) .

However, with respect to a "Non-Towered" airport, I cannot find any specific U.S. Federal Aviation Regulation (FAR) that prohibits an aircraft taking off while another aircraft is still exiting the runway.

Nevertheless, 14 CFR [Parts 91.13 (a)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-91#p-91.13(a)) and/or [91.111 (a)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-91#p-91.111(a)) might possibly apply:

**91.13 Careless or reckless operation.**

> (a) **Aircraft operations for the purpose of air navigation.**  No person may operate an aircraft in a careless or reckless manner so as to endanger the life or property of another.

**91.111 Operating near other aircraft.**

> (a) No person may operate an aircraft so close to another aircraft as to create a collision hazard.

The applicability of these regulations would, in my opinion, be dependent upon a variety of factors such as:

1. How close did the other aircraft actually come to your aircraft;
2. How high was the other aircraft when it passed above you while you were still on the runway;
3. Was there an actual collision hazard (see 14 CFR 91.111 (a)) above.

There may be other factors that can reasonably be considered when evaluating the applicability of 91.13 (a) and/or 91.111 (a).

Also, as a note, with respect to 91.13 (a), "actual" danger is not required, only "potential" danger.

Lastly, in my opinion, you  would have to have a witness to attest to the circumstances within the context of the event to support the "danger" and/or "hazard" aspects of the regulations mentioned above.

Comment: Good answer; possible additional references are the Pilot/Controller Glossary term [CLEAR OF THE RUNWAY](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg_html/glossary-c.html) and [the 7110.65 3–9–6**b**](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap3_section_9.html#3NJ3acJACK).